# JDBC connection on a port other than 8080

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

When I try to run a J2EE Web application on a port other than 8080 JDBC connection to MySQL fails.
Details below.
http://localhost:8080/Application1/welcome.jsp

### JDBC Connection string

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1";
String username = "user1";
String password = "password1";

Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection( url, username, password );
```

This works fine.

### Problem

I then stop client side of things. Change the Tomcat settings to be port 9090 and restart the application.

http://localhost:9090/Application1/welcome.jsp

welcome jsp loads up ok. But the page after that with SQL data page fails. Error log states the jdbc connection failed.

### Error Message

Error - HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

### details:

type Exception report
message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Book.init(Book.java:55)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

---

MySQL server is up and running fine. When I switch back back to original port(8080) everything works fine. ie http://localhost:8080/Application1/welcome.jsp

I am using windows eclipse as my IDE. MySQL56, Tomcat8, Java7.

Any ideas on how I could create a jdbc connection for a different port?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: There is no relation between changing tomcat port number and your db connection. Both are running on different ports.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing related to the MySql connection when you just change the WebApplication port. Are you sure you just changed it? did you check the MySql service if it is running, and the port is 3306 as well ?

Comment: WebApplication port change was to confirm that there was no issue on the servlet container.

Comment: MySql service is running and the port is 3306 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Initially 
http://localhost:8080/Application1/welcome.jsp was working ok.
http://localhost:9090/Application1/welcome.jsp was not working ok.

I then added the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar into the WEB-INF/lib/ folder and then it started working for multiple ports.
ie
http://localhost:8080/Application1/welcome.jsp - ok
http://localhost:9090/Application1/welcome.jsp - ok

Problem solved. Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Because your error message is saying class not found, it means you did not have correct driver jar before.